# Possible mistake in evaluation of $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {x \tan^{-1}(ax)}{x^2+b^2}\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, solution-verification

**Attempt**:
Using Feynman's trick, let-
$$I(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac { x \tan^{-1}(ax)}{x^2+b^2}\ dx$$
Partially differentiating with respect to $a$, we get-
$$I'(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {(x^2+a^2)-a^2}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)}\ dx$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {dx}{x^2+b^2}-\frac {a^2}{a^2-b^2}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {(x^2+a^2)-(x^2+b^2)}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)}\ dx$$
$$=\frac {\pi}{2b}-\frac {a^2}{a^2-b^2}\left( \frac {\pi}{2b}-\frac {\pi}{2a}\right)$$
$$=\frac {\pi}{2(a+b)}$$

Thus, $$I(a)=\frac {\pi \ln(a+b)}{2}+C$$
Since $I(0)=0$, we get $C=-\frac {\pi \ln b}{2}$.
So we get, $$I(a)=\frac {\pi \ln(\frac ab +1)}{2}$$
Is this correct? A concern of mine is, can Feynman's trick be applied when two or more parameters are present simultaneously, as in this case?

Comment: You computed the integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x \color{red}{\tan^{-1}(ax)}}{x^2+b^2} \, \mathrm{d}x,$$ whereas the original integral is $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x \color{blue}{\tan(ax)}}{x^2+b^2} \, \mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: Note that $$\frac{x \arctan(ax)}{x^2+b^2} \sim \frac{\pi}{2x} \quad\text{as} \quad x \to \infty,$$ so the integral will diverge to $+\infty$ by the limit comparison test. It seems true, however, that $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\arctan(a/x)}{x^2+b^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{2}\log\left(\frac{a}{b}+1\right).$$